# My checkboxes are always checked. I cannot create them unchecked

Tags: itext

I have a form that I have created with a table.  In side the cells of the table I have checkboxes.  Some of these checkboxes need to be checked and others do not.

I googled around and came up with way to put checkboxes in the table.  Here is my method that is creating a few of the table cells.

```
private void createFourColumnBody(String[] rowLabels, PdfPTable table) throws DocumentException {
    PdfFormField checkboxGroupField = PdfFormField.createCheckBox(writer);
    for (String label : rowLabels) {
        PdfPCell cell = table.getDefaultCell();
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(label));
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(table.getDefaultCell());
        cell.setCellEvent(new CellField(writer, checkboxGroupField, true));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(table.getDefaultCell());
        cell.setCellEvent(new CellField(writer, checkboxGroupField, false));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("                    "));
        table.addCell(cell);
    }

    getDocument().add(table);
    writer.addAnnotation(checkboxGroupField);

}
```

This is the class that is called to create the checkboxes.

```
protected class CellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
    private PdfFormField parent;

    private String partialFieldName;
    private PdfWriter writer;
    private boolean checked;

    public CellField(PdfWriter writer, PdfFormField parent, boolean checked) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] cb) {
        try {
            createCheckboxField(rect);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private void createCheckboxField(Rectangle rect) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        RadioCheckField rf = new RadioCheckField(writer, new Rectangle(rect.getLeft(2), rect.getBottom(2),
                rect.getRight(2), rect.getTop(2)), partialFieldName, "");
        rf.setChecked(checked);
        rf.setBorderColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
        rf.setBackgroundColor(GrayColor.GRAYWHITE);
        rf.setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK);

        parent.addKid(rf.getCheckField());
    }
}
```

You can see in the first method that I have the checked boolean marked as true for the first checkbox and false for the second checkbox, but it always creates a pdf with the checkbox checked.  I have tried removing the checkmark and just drawing a rectangle, but it has been to no avail.  What needs to happen to make the `rf.setChecked(false)` work like it seems that it should.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have [double posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034036/itext-checkbox-is-always-checked/18056958#18056958) I will give you some hints what's wrong with the code:

1. Since you want to add several checkboxes you have to create your checkboxes inside the loop (however add the annotions afterwards which is a bit weird imho)
2. Why did you add a partial name?
3. You set an empty option (aka export value) which is invalid
4. [optional] no need to (unnecessarily) recreated the rectangle again.

Ok here's the code which works fine:

```
public void createFourColumnBody(String[] rowLabels, PdfPTable table) throws DocumentException {
    this.doc.open();

    ArrayList<PdfFormField> list = new ArrayList<PdfFormField>();

    for (int i=0;i<rowLabels.length;i++) {

        //PdfFormField checkboxGroupField = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(this.writer,false);
        PdfFormField checkbox1 = PdfFormField.createCheckBox(this.writer);
        //create a unique name 
        checkbox1.setFieldName("checkbox-"+i);

        PdfFormField checkbox2 = PdfFormField.createCheckBox(this.writer);
        checkbox2.setFieldName("checkbox+"+i);
        //use for autofill
        //checkbox2.setFieldName("checkbox-"+i);

        PdfPCell cell = table.getDefaultCell();
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(rowLabels[i]));
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(table.getDefaultCell());
        cell.setCellEvent(new CellField(this.writer, checkbox1, true,"1"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(table.getDefaultCell());
        cell.setCellEvent(new CellField(this.writer, checkbox2, false,"1"));
        //use for autofill
        //cell.setCellEvent(new CellField(this.writer, checkbox1, true,"1"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("                    "));
        table.addCell(cell);

        list.add(checkbox1);
        list.add(checkbox2);
    }
    this.doc.add(table);

    for(PdfFormField field: list){
        this.writer.addAnnotation(field);
    }
}
```

---

```
    protected class CellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
    private PdfFormField parent;

    private PdfWriter writer;
    private boolean checked;
    private String onValue;

    public CellField(PdfWriter writer, PdfFormField parent, boolean checked, String onValue) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.checked = checked;
        this.onValue = onValue;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] cb) {
        try {
            this.createCheckboxField(rect);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void createCheckboxField(Rectangle rect) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        RadioCheckField bt = new RadioCheckField(this.writer, rect, null, this.onValue);
        bt.setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CROSS);
        bt.setChecked(this.checked);
        this.parent.addKid(bt.getCheckField());
    }
}
```

Regarding the `setCheckType` compare the other post.

Comment: I was able to get this code working with a PdfStamper in C#. For the most part it is all the same except the part where the annotation is written to the PdfWriiter (I assume that is what this.writer is above). The main difference is I had to use _pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(f, **1**) (where 1 is the page number). I have a question/concern about this approach. What happens when the table crosses over a page break? Do I need to figure out how to track/control that or will it automagically figure it out?