# Facing issue on Itext checkBox on CellField

Tags: java, itext

I am using class the below to add check box and along with some text

```
Class A {
    public void createFourColumnBody() throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException {
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
        com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer1 = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\PDF_Java.pdf", false));
        document.open();
        float[] widths = new float[] {
            30 f, 30 f
        };
        com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable(widths);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        PdfFormField checkboxGroupField = PdfFormField.createCheckBox(writer1);
        PdfPCell cell = table.getDefaultCell();
        PdfPCell cell12;
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("checkbox3"));
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell12 = new PdfPCell(table.getDefaultCell());
        cell12.setCellEvent(new CellField(writer1, checkboxGroupField, true));
        table.addCell(cell12);
        writer1.addAnnotation(checkboxGroupField);
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException {
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.createFourColumnBody();
    }
}
```

I am facing the issue at the fallowing line in the above code

`cell12.setCellEvent(new CellField(writer1, checkboxGroupField, true));`

The issue is 'Can not find the symbol class CellField'

Any help ?

Comment: does it exist CellField class?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that you get the error *'Can not find the symbol class CellField'* because that is not an official iText class. Check the [iText 5 API documentation](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/) and you won't find it.

Maybe it's a class you wrote, but forgot to import. Maybe it's a class someone else wrote, but you forgot to copy it. Did you copy your code from an example? If so, please show us where you found that example.

I Googled for "setCellEvent(new CellField" and I found a reference to this question:
[My checkboxes are always checked. I cannot create them unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629628)

In this case the `CellField` class was written like this:

```
protected class CellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
    private PdfFormField parent;

    private String partialFieldName;
    private PdfWriter writer;
    private boolean checked;

    public CellField(PdfWriter writer, PdfFormField parent, boolean checked) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] cb) {
        try {
            createCheckboxField(rect);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private void createCheckboxField(Rectangle rect) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        RadioCheckField rf = new RadioCheckField(writer, new Rectangle(rect.getLeft(2), rect.getBottom(2),
                rect.getRight(2), rect.getTop(2)), partialFieldName, "");
        rf.setChecked(checked);
        rf.setBorderColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
        rf.setBackgroundColor(GrayColor.GRAYWHITE);
        rf.setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK);

        parent.addKid(rf.getCheckField());
    }
}
```

If that is indeed where you found the inspiration to use a class named `CellField` that was written by someone else, make sure to copy it together with the other code you are using.

Also avoid losing Karma by copying code that you don't understand. If you strive for greatness, you should be fully aware of every decision you make. This includes understanding the code you borrow from others. If you don't strive for greatness... Well, we usually don't bother with people like that, do we?